# How to prepare route to get controller ,method names from url

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get controller , method names from url and redirect to particular route.

This is for recent codeigniter version 4.

$routes->add('(:any)/(:any)','$1::$2');

For suppose :- domain/text1/text2  should redirect to text2 method of text1 controller.

Answer (score 0):

make route for it:config/routes.php

```
$route['text1/(:any)/(:any)']='controller_name/method_name/$1/$2';
```